# Faster Matrix Multiplication in CUDA

Tags: c, cuda, matrix-multiplication

Currently, I made a neural networks program in the cuda c. Because I needed to manipulate the matrix multiplication, I did not use CUBLAS for MM. I use the following code for MM. I was wondering if any one has some advice to make it faster which can be very helpful since I need to use MM millions of times during learning. Thanks. 
This is the MakeFile:

```
# cuda root
_CUDA_ROOT_ = /usr/local/cuda

NVCC = nvcc
# include and lib paths
INCLUDES=-I${_CUDA_ROOT_}/include
LIB_PATH=-L${_CUDA_ROOT_}/lib64

# libraries to link against
LIB= -lcudart -lcublas
CU_SRC= main.cu
EXE=$(CU_SRC:.cu=)
#------------------------------
# Choose your gpu arch
SM = sm_35
all: $(EXE)
$(EXE): $(CU_SRC)
        $(NVCC) -arch $(SM) $(CU_SRC) -o $(EXE) $(LIB_PATH) $(LIB)

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.cu_o $(EXE)
```

This is the MM code:

```
__global__
void matrixMulti(float* A_d, float* B_d, float* C_d, int m, int k, int n)
{
    __shared__ float ds_A[TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];
    __shared__ float ds_B[TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];
    int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;
    float sum = 0;

    for(int t=0; t<(n-1)/TILE_WIDTH+1; t++)
    {
        if(row<m && t*TILE_WIDTH+tx<n)
            ds_A[ty][tx] = A_d[row*n + t*TILE_WIDTH+tx];
        else
            ds_A[ty][tx] = 0.0;
        if(t*TILE_WIDTH+ty<n && col<k)
            ds_B[ty][tx] = B_d[(t*TILE_WIDTH+ty)*k + col];
        else
            ds_B[ty][tx] = 0.0;
        __syncthreads();
        for(int i=0; i<TILE_WIDTH; i++)
            sum += ds_A[ty][i] * ds_B[i][tx];
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if(row<m && col<k)
        C_d[col+row*k] = sum;
}
```

This is the example of main part of the code:

```
const int TILE_WIDTH = 32;

int main()
{
    int m, k, n;
    m = 10000, k = 10000, n = 10000;
    float *A, *B, *C;
    A = new float[m*n];
    B = new float[n*k];
    C = new float[m*k];
    float *A_d, *B_d, *C_d;
    for (int i=0; i<m*n; i++)
    {
        A[i] = 2;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n*k; i++)
    {
        B[i] = 3;
    }
    cudaMalloc(&A_d, sizeof(float)*m*n);
    cudaMalloc(&B_d, sizeof(float)*n*k);
    cudaMalloc(&C_d, sizeof(float)*m*k);
    cudaMemcpy(A_d, A, sizeof(float)*m*n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(B_d, B, sizeof(float)*k*n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    dim3 dimGrid((k-1)/TILE_WIDTH+1, (m-1)/TILE_WIDTH+1, 1);
    dim3 dimBlock(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_WIDTH, 1);
    matrixMulti<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(A_d, B_d, C_d, m, k, n);
    cudaMemcpy(C, C_d, sizeof(float)*m*k, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why cuBLAS and the BLAS primitives for matrix multiplication are not adequate? Your code is not that transparent.

Comment: It is because I need to add more things inside the matrix multiplication code and this is just the basis of my code. Sorry if it is not transparent. The task is to get C_d = A_d * B_d, A_d dim is m*n, B_d dim is n*k.

Comment: And the algorithm used is Tiled Matrix Multiplication .

Comment: Could you at least add complete kernel code someone could compile? What is a typical value of `TILE_WIDTH`?  What is a typical problem size?

Comment: I added the rest of the code for a simple example, I hope that it helps.

Comment: Another possible approach is implementing two distinct kernels to be called in sequence (one for matrix mul. and one for the "other things"). Although not well documented it should be possible to mix cuBLAS calls and custom kernels, so there is really no need to try to reinvent the wheel and write a cuBLAS-alike kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The main reason I do not use cuBLAS is that for example I have the weights of all layers (for neural networks) in one array and I need to separate the weights of each layer and do the multiplication for each layer. In my current code, it is easy and I need to just add one for loop and a few lines to the code. But for cuBLAS, I could not find a good solution for it ( how can I separate a part of a big array and give it to cuBLAS without so much of burden) Please, consider I must put all weights in one array. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Can't you just offset the pointer you pass to cuBLAS? Unless the data for the layers is interleaved in some way.

Comment: So I am a bit confused how I can offset the pointer. Suppose that I have matrix A1 with the dimension (10, 10) and A2(5,5) and A3(2,2). Now I put all in array A which is like A[A1 A2 A3]  which means the 100 first items of array A are A1 and the next 25 items A2 and the last 4 are A3.

Comment: Now if I want to use cublasSgemm and access A2 and multiply with some array like B, how can I do it?  Thanks a lot

Comment: Part of making things run fast on the GPU is effective data organization.  If you force an arbitrary array definition, then you might not be able to use cublas effectively. Instead, you might want to think about "what array definitions to hold my weights will allow me to use cublas". And the code you've shown here is nothing more than *ordinary naive tiled matrix multiply", so it's not much surprise that others can't easily discern your real intent. The cuDNN library was created specifically to address the problem of effectively using cublas-type operations on arrays of neural network weights.

Comment: Follow-up questions about how to offset a pointer don't really belong here and should really be in a standalone separate. However `A + 100` should give a pointer to the first element of A2...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, be really sure this is what you want to do. Without describing the manipulations you want to do, it's hard to comment on this, but be aware that matrix multiplication is an n-cubed operation. If your manipulations are not the same complexity, chances are you'll do better simply using cuBLAS.

Why is this? cuBLAS will probably be faster than anything you'll write, and will be much more maintainable as it will follow new GPU architectures. The best implementation of something like GEMM will vary based on architecture, so any code you're writing now for your hardware will have to be re-optimised for new hardware.

Now, to the question. There's a number of techniques you should consider to optimise this code:

1. **Compute multiple output values per thread**. This reduces the pressure on your shared memory as tile data can be used in multiple calculations.
2. **Fix the bank conflicts in shared memory**. This should be covered well by the documentation.
3. **Vectorise shared memory loads and stores**. I notice you're compiling for sm_35. This architecture's shared memory banks each have a bandwidth of 64 bits/clock. Loading a single float is only 32 bits, so you won't get full bandwidth on floats without vectorization. You should look at float2/float4 types.
4. **Consider double buffering**. Load data into one shared memory tile while operating on another. This allows the high latency of global memory operations to be hidden much more effectively, reduces the synchronisation overhead, and often tends to perform better. It uses twice as much shared memory though, as you need two tiles at once.

There are a number of papers on the implementation of matrix multiplication on GPUs, I suggest you check them out. You'll get a lot more detail from these papers than you will asking broad questions on SO.

Finally... are you sure you don't want to use cuBLAS? I wouldn't count on getting 75% of cuBLAS performance, and even that will be a challenge.

Comment: This is the only correct answer to this sort of question

Comment: Thanks for your response. The main reason I do not use cuBLAS is that for example I have the weights of all layers (for neural networks) in one array  and I need to separate the weights of each layer and do the multiplication for each layer.  In my current code, it is easy and I need to just add one for loop  and a few lines to the code. But for cuBLAS, I could not find a good solution for it ( how can I separate a part of a big array and give it to cuBLAS without so much of burden) Please, consider I must put all weights in one array.

Comment: Do you have a solution for this? If do not, please give me some detailed explanations about your solutions cause they are very general. Would you please tell me for example for your first solution what should I do in this current code?

Comment: So I am a bit confused how I can offset the pointer. Suppose that I have matrix A1 with the dimension (10, 10) and A2(5,5) and A3(2,2). Now I put all in array A which is like A[A1 A2 A3] which means the 100 first items of array A are A1 and the next 25 items A2 and the last 4 are A3

Comment: Now if I want to use cublasSgemm and access A2 and multiply with some array like B, how can I do it? Thanks a lot